# Does $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{3^{2n-1}}\right)$ have a closed result?

Tags: infinite-product

Does $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\dfrac{1}{3^{2n-1}}\right)$ has a closed result?

I have computed it by *WolframAlpha* and got a numerical solution $1.564934\cdots$.

Comment: The numerical value you got is not what you claim, it is the value of  $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1 \color{red}{-} \frac{1}{3^{2n-1}}\right)^{\color{red}{-1}}$ instead.

Comment: It seems to me that an exact expression can be obtained but I need to check the details to see if it really works. You start by taking the logarithm, expanding the logarithm in series, interchanging the two summations and summing the inner one (which is a geometric series). The summation you're left with can be computed by replacing 3 by $x$ and substituting $x = \exp(i t)$. The summation  can be expressed as a sum of residues and evaluated by evaluating a residue at zero.

Comment: You can address this infinite product by taking the logarithm and applying the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula. But you'll get by no means a closed-formula and you will require a polylog function.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the result Wolfram Alpha gave me (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+of+(1+%2B+3%5E(1+-+2*n))+from+n%3D1+to+infinity).

The result, as written in the page is
$$\frac{1}{4}\left(-3;\frac{1}{9}\right)_{\infty }$$ where appears the Pochhammer symbol.

Its decimal representation is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

Answer (score 0):

One can derive the following result using complex analysis:

$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\dfrac{1}{3^{2n-1}}\right) = 3^{-\frac{1}{24}}\exp\left(\frac{\pi^2}{24\log(3)}\right)\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{a^{2n-1}}\right)\tag{1}$$

where

$$a = \exp\left(\frac{\pi^2}{\log(3)}\right)\approx 7972.08287589$$

So, it's not a closed form result, but note that because $a\gg 3$, the product on the r.h.s. converges much faster than the original product.

To derive this result, take the logarithm of the product to turn it into a summation:

$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3^{2n-1}}\right) $$

Expand the logarithm in series, exchange the two summations and perform the inner summation:

$$S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}3^k}{k}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3^{-2nk}= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k\left(3^k-3^{-k}\right)}$$

We can write this a a summation over all integers except zero, as the summand is an even function:

$$S = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k\neq 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k\sinh(\log(3) k)}$$

Alternating summations over integers of a meromorphic functions $f(z)$ can sometimes be computed by considering the contour integral of $\dfrac{\pi f(z)}{\sin(\pi z)}$ over a contour of radius $R$ around the origin. If in the limit of $R\to \infty$ the contour integral vanishes, then the sum of all residues must be zero. The summation is (in our case) up to a minus sign given by the sum of the residues at the poles of $\dfrac{1}{\sin(\pi z)}$.

It's easily verified that the contour integral will indeed tend to zero for $R\to \infty$, therefore $S$ is given by the sum of the residues at zero and at the zeroes of $\sinh(\log(3) z)$ of the function:

$$g(z) = \frac{\pi}{4 z\sin(\pi z)\sinh(\log(3) z)}$$

The residue at zero is:

$$\frac{\pi^2 - \log^2(3)}{24\log(3)}$$

The sum of the residues at the zeroes of  $\sinh(\log(3) z)$  is:

$$\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k\neq 1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k\sinh\left(\dfrac{\pi^2 k}{\log(3)}\right)}$$

Exponentiating the sum of the residues yields (1).

Comment: It converges linearly, like the original formula, doesn't it ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I've made that explicit by giving the answer in product form.

Comment: This is really impressive ! Using 10 terms in the product leads to more than 80 correct significant figures.